# Asp.Net How to populate dropdownlist from another dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

in Asp.net Webforms i have 2 dropdownlists which are populating from database codebehind.

I want to populate second ddl with first ddl filter.

Here is my code

```
$(function () {
        $('select#ContentPlaceHolder_ddl1').change(function () {
            var param1= $(this).val();
            var dataString = { 'param1': param1, 'tip' : 1};
            //alert(scope);
            //building unit
            $('select#ContentPlaceHolder_ddl2').empty();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'ChangeDDL.aspx/listele',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                   $.each(data, function (key, DropDownListItem) {
                       $('select#ContentPlaceHolder_ddl2').append(
                                '<option value="' + DropDownListItem.value + '">'
                                + DropDownListItem.optionText +
                                '</option>');

                    });
                }

            });
```

I can get data from html but i want the data with DropDownListItem class. My class is here

```
public class DropDownListItem
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string optionText { get; set; }
}
```

in ChangeDDL.aspx i am trying to return data but i don't know how . Here is my aspx file

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<DropDownListItem> listele(string scope, int tip)
{
    if (tip == 1)
    {
        List<DropDownListItem> obj = new List<DropDownListItem>();
        DataTable dt = (..sql query)
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            obj.Add(new DropDownListItem
            {
                value = dr["building_unit"].ToString(),
                optionText = dr["building_unit"].ToString()
            });
        }
        return obj;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I cannot access to listele function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to enable the scriptmanager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Try [this tutotial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769238/Call-Server-Side-Code-using-ASP-NET-AJAX-and-jQuer). It explains how to use AJAX with ASP.NET quite well.

Comment: How can i use getSecondDDL in my js code. is this enough to use as  url: 'ChangeDDL.aspx',

Comment: url: "YourNameOfTheASPX.aspx/MethodName" see [this tutotial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx) it's very easy to understand

Comment: I cannot access to my function listele as i created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150938/discussion-between-t-jung-and-ender-aric).

Comment: I put a breakpoint to my ChangeDDL.aspx/listele method. But nothing happened.